# $(i\partial_t)^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{it\Delta} f = (-\Delta )^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{it\Delta} f$?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis

Put $\langle x \rangle ^s = (1 + |x|)^{1/2},$ and  $|\nabla |^s $ denotes the Fourier  multiplier with symbol $|\xi|^s$,  that is, $\widehat{|\nabla |^s f} = |\xi|^s \hat{f}.$

Put $ \langle \nabla \rangle = (1- \Delta)^{1/2}$ (And how should I define this? any motivation?) and

we define
$\|f\|_{H^{s}} =  \|\langle \nabla \rangle ^{s} f \|_{L^2}$

Questions:

(1)  How I should define $(- \Delta )^{1/2}$?

How to justify $(i\partial_t)^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{it\Delta} f = (-\Delta )^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{it\Delta} f$, $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R \times \mathbb R^d)$ (Schwartz space) (where $e^{it\Delta}$ is a Schrodinger propagator )
(2) Let $K$ be  any compact set in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R^d.$ Can  we show

$\|e^{it\Delta } f \|_{H^{1/2}_{t,x}(K)} \leq  C \| \langle  - \Delta \rangle^{1/2} e^{it\Delta} f \|_{L^{2}(K)} \leq C  \|\nabla f \|_{L^2}$

(Do I need to use the H\"olders inequality and (1) to prove (2))

Motivation: I am trying to understand the proof of Inverse Strichatz estimates [Proposition 3.2, p.242 (Chapter 3)](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-0348-0736-4_17#page-1). The above fact has been used in it (see p.242).

Edit: I just saw [here, p.12](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=terrance+tao+little+wood+paley+projections), we  may say $|\nabla|^s = (-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}$
. And so $(-\Delta )^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{it\Delta} f(\xi) = |\xi| \widehat{e^{it\Delta}f}(\xi)= |\xi| e^{-it |\xi|^2}\hat{f}(\xi)  $, But now how should I handle $(i\partial_t)^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{it\Delta} f$?

We may write $\widehat {\langle \nabla \rangle^s} f(\xi) = \langle \xi \rangle ^s \hat{f}(\xi).$ How should I define $\langle -\Delta \rangle ^{s}$?

Comment: It might help if you define $(i\partial_t)^{1/2}$.

Comment: (1) via the spectral theorem?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy $i\partial_t$ with domain $H^1(\mathbb R)$ is a self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\mathbb R)$: can't one use the spectral theorem also in this case? Or does your question points to the fact that the OP does not specify which of the most usual fractional derivatives (Riemann-Liouville or Caputo) he's picking?

Comment: If you are comfortable with $|\nabla|$, I do not see how you can be uncomfortable with $\sqrt{1-\Delta}$. In this context (dispersive PDEs) those symbols are always meant to be Fourier multipliers.